# jqGrid Add Link Column Binded with Specific Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have this ASP.Net Page with jqGrid, all what I want is to add a link column in the grid that when pressed, it does a JavaScript function, like open a jQuery Dialog in the Page...

I was able to change the first column to link coulmn using column formatter, but I wasn't able to make the link do a JavaScript function...

My Code:

```
colModel = [
        { name: 'SR', index: 'SR', width: 90, fixed: true, align: 'center', formatter: 'link', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '#'} },
        { name: 'NextCallBackDate', index: 'NextCallBack', width: 100, fixed: true, align: 'left' }]
```

Comment: How do you populate your grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've acomplished this in PHP but it should work any where. When you prepare the data, change  the column like this:

Instead of `field='value'` you can do `field='<a onclick="foo(this)">value</a>'`

The function should look like this:

```
function foo (item){
alert ($(item).html());
}
```

Comment: I don't have code similar to yours, I just fill rows in the WebService as JSON Format, where are you using this code...?

Comment: Post the web-service. I use this code when I prepare the json

Comment: AAH, do you mean that when filling this particular column, I replace my value with "<a onclick="foo()">MYvalue</a>" ?!!!

Comment: Just one thing, how do I make it underlined...?!

Comment: And how do I get the selected cell value in JavaScript...!